# How to create this text effect with CSS?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Is it possible to create a text effect like this with CSS using some peudo element or so?? This effect where a text element is in the back of the heading text.
[image]

Comment: just use absolute position on either :before or :after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Here is a very basic example that I threw together.  Essentially, use a `position:absolute` using the `:before` CSS selector.

```css
.block {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

h2 {
  padding: 1em 0;
}

h2:before {
  content: attr(data-num);
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: .4em;
  color: #eee;
}

h2 span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h2 data-num="01"><span>Research</span></h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p><a href="#">Find out more</a></p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <h2 data-num="02"><span>Wireframing</span></h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <p><a href="#">Find out more</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Try this:

HTML:

```
<!-- use the custom "heading-number" attribute to insert content into the :after pseudo-element -->
<span class="numbered-heading" heading-number="01">Research</span>
<span class="numbered-heading" heading-number="02">Wireframing</span>
```

CSS:

```
.numbered-heading {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 20px;
}

.numbered-heading:after {
  display: block;
  content: attr(heading-number);

  /* Absolutely position the numbers here */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  font-size: 3em;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Here's a demo in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usfrfdje/768/

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to approach this would be to define the number explicitly in your HTML then add a data attribute that displays the content over the number using the :before pseudo selector in CSS.

```
    <h1 data-text="Research">01</h1>

    h1 {
        font-size: 72px;
        color: #ccc;
        line-height: 0;
    }

    h1:before {
        content: attr(data-text);
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #333;
        position: absolute;
   }
```

View a demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGOWLb

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve a similar effect using absolute positioning and some nested elements, similar to the example code below.

```
<div class="bgText">
Back Test
<span class="headingText">Front Text</span>
</div>

.bgText {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
   font-size: 32px;
}
.headingText {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="text-bg" data-bg-text="01">
  Research
</div>

.text-bg::before{
  content:attr(data-bg-text);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.1;
  font-size: 4rem;
}
.text-bg{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top:1rem;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kalaikt/0ox6oj1u/